# how to sum values inside array hash with same key in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

i want to sum values inside array hash with same key in ruby, example :

```
a = [{"nationalvoice"=>"5"}, {"nationalvoice"=>"1"}]
```

how to make the array of hash to like this :

```
a = [{"nationalvoice"=>"6"}]
```

Comment: fix problem using @sawa answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{"nationalvoice"=>"5"}, {"nationalvoice"=>"1"}]
.group_by{|h| h.keys.first}.values
.map{|a| {
  a.first.keys.first =>
  a.inject(0){|sum, h| sum + h.values.first.to_i}.to_s
}}
# => [{"nationalvoice"=>"6"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

My **functional** solution

```
array = [{"foo" => "1"}, {"bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "4"}]

array.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.map do |k, v| 
  Hash[k, v.reduce(0) { |acc, n| acc + n.values.first.to_i }]
end 

# => [{"foo"=>5}, {"bar"=>2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
[{ "nationalvoice" => [{"nationalvoice"=>"5"}, {"nationalvoice"=>"1"}].reduce(0) {|s, v| s + v.values.first.to_i } }]
# => [{"nationalvoice"=>6}]
```

with `#replace`:

```
a = [{"nationalvoice"=>"5"}, {"nationalvoice"=>"1"}]
a.replace( [{ a.first.keys.first => a.reduce(0) {|s, v| s + v.values.first.to_i } }] )
# => [{"nationalvoice"=>6}]
```

Comment: Downvoter, and argue?

Comment: Maybe this solution is not generic enough. It doesn't work for different keys.

Comment: @JosuaSchmid whuch keys ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd do as below :

```
a = [{"nationalvoice"=>"1"}, {"foo" => "1"}, {"bar" => "2"}, {"nationalvoice"=>"5"}] 
new = a.group_by { | h | h.keys.first }.map do |k,v|
     v.each_with_object({}) do | h1,h2|
        h2.merge!(h1) { |key,old,new| (old.to_i + new.to_i).to_s }
     end
end

new # => [{"nationalvoice"=>"6"}, {"foo"=>"1"}, {"bar"=>"2"}]
```

Comment: Try `a = [{"foo" => "1"}, {"bar" => "2"}]`.